# Probability of $\max(2x, y) - \min(2x, y) < 3^{-1}$

Tags: probability

Given two independent random variables $x$ and $y$ distributed uniformly on a segment $[0, 1]$, we need to find the probability of
$$\max(2x, y) - \min(2x, y) < 3^{-1}$$

---

That was a question in an [online competition](https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/4032/problems/I/). I didn't know how to approach it, so I've written a program which does that random experiment $10^{11}$ times and I got $p = 0.3056$, which happened to be correct.

They didn't prohibit that approach, but I think there is a logical (instead of computational) way to find the answer. I would appreciate any explanations.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kpqkhvr3mw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kpqkhvr3mw

We require the region between the red & blue lines & inside the unit circle. It is easier to calculate the regions out side of this.

The triangle above the red line has area $\frac{1}{9}$ & the triangle below the blue line has area $\frac{1}{4}$ & the area of the rectangle on the right is $\frac{1}{3}$. The area we require is $1-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}$.

So the probability is $\color{red}{\frac{11}{36}}= \color{blue}{ 0.3056 \cdots}$.